# After update to MacOS Big Sur 11.7.7 desktop aliases fail to open the original folders

Tags: finder, desktop, alias

After the upgrade to BigSur 11.7.7. all of the folder aliases on my desktop fail to open the original folders in Finder.
Similar bug to the one reported in "MacOS 11.4 Big Sur has issues with alias … - Apple Community" .

My bug is slightly different. As in the bug above, double clicking on the alias fails to open the target folder, instead displaying the files for Macintosh>Users>timothychilders.

But unlike the original bug report above, using a right click to 'Get Info' shows the correct path to the Original folder. And the button Select New Original... lets me click it and will let me navigate to the Original folder and select it. But after I do this the finder STILL displays the files for Macintosh>Users>timothychilders.

I tried both a Shutdown, and a Restart with no change in behavior.

Also tried to delete the alias on the desktop, and create a brand new alias and moved that new alias to the desktop. The new desktop alias exhibits the same behavior.

A post on StackExchange>AskDifferent suggested deleting the apple.com.finder.plist from Library/Preferences and rebooting to let MacOS Finder build a new .plist.  but I didn't fine apple.com.finder.plist there, even after a reboot.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Possible Fix:**
Add the parent folder to your Finder Sidebar.

**More Info:**
I had a very similar problem you described. After upgrading my 2019 iMac to Sonoma recently (skipped a few OS versions), I had a few aliases on my desktop to various folders. Double-clicking those aliases opened the correct folder for some, but opened my user folder for others. After a lot of searching and testing, I narrowed down the problem I was experiencing and found it to be quite specific, making it hard for outside support to recreate the issue. Based on another post I found over on the [Apple community forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253715557?answerId=256998465022&sortBy=best#256998465022), I realized **this bug only appeared when using the Columns Finder view**. If switching to List, Icons or Gallery view, closing the Finder window and then re-opening the alias, it worked correctly. But I am a die-hard Columns view user, so this wasn't a great solution for me. And if you switch views often, this can give the impression of "It fixed itself!" and then the next day it is broken again. I saw this in a couple of other posts about the issue.

I compared the aliases I had to other folders that did work even in Columns view and after even more testing, I found that this only affected aliases pointing to *any* folder inside my ~/Documents folder. It is possible that this bug could affect other special folders like this, in case your problematic aliases weren't pointing to Documents subfolders. In the end I found **the problem is likely tied to your Finder Sidebar**. I have customized and trimmed my down over the years to only a few folders, like Dropbox, my user folder and some development folders I access often. But if **I added the ~/Documents folder back into my sidebar, all of my Desktop aliases to Documents subfolders worked, even in Columns view**.

Again, the seemingly unrelated setup of a customized sidebar could make this bug seem impossible for Support staff to recreate the issue. And interestingly enough, if you do not have your user folder in the sidebar, it will cause that default window to go all the way back to your hard drive folder. This makes me think that it could affect other "special case" folders.

As a side note, I did try creating the aliases by dragging and dropping, through the context menu (and then moving the alias to the desktop) and even with symlinks created through Terminal. They all had the same behavior and the same fix worked for all of them.

I hope this helps you or anyone else that might be experiencing this bug. If anyone finds out any other specifics about it, please update with details that you find.